# Disabling Stripe extension breaks database

Tags: extension, stripe

After clicking "disable" on the Stripe extension, visiting civi gave me an error 500 and does not make an entry in the error log. But going to Drupal home kicks out the following error message:

`Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/Payment/Stripe.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Civi\Payment\System::getByProcessor() (line 59 of /home/ourbase/public_html/prbrc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php).`

The file it's looking for does exist, BTW.

I've fixed this before (see answer), but I just want to uninstall the extension -- it never for us worked anyway.

Comment: This is a variant of this question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15813/fatal-error-after-upgrading-to-4-7-13-from-4-7-11/15816#15816

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting your site back online, in phpmyadmin:

1. In table `civicrm_extension`, enable stripe (change 0 to 1)
2. In table `payment_processor`, disable any using stripe (change 1 to 0)

This should allow your site to load.

Deleting stripe (warning: stripe may be related to some transactions, check before doing this):

- Make sure none of your donation pages are using stripe
- Delete any payment methods using stripe
- Delete the payment processor "stripe"
- Disable extension "stripe"
- Uninstall extension "stripe"

You'll still see it on the list of extensions with an install link. To get rid of it, you'll have to remove the com.drastikbydesign.stripe folder in /sites/default/files/civicrm/extension (or whatever your extensions directory is).